# Angular 4+. How can a service http method call itself again with another input value?

Tags: angular

How can a service http method call itself again with another input value when there was an error while calling this method at first time? Are there better ways to do this?

```
private subscribedMethod: Subscription;

public someMethod(): void {
    this.subscribedMethod = this.someService.update("first value") // call a service method with "first value"
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                if (data) {
                    // do something
                }
            },
            (err: any) => {
                if (err.status === 404) {
                    this.subscribedMethod.unsubscribe();
                    this.someService.update("second value") // call the same service method with "second value"
                        .subscribe(
                            (data: any) => {
                                if (data) {
                                    // do something
                                }
                        });
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Do I understand your question right that you want to do the exact same request again after it failed in an endless loop in some way? And can you be more precise what version of Angular you want to do this as ng4-5 has different http-clients

Comment: I want to get successful result by calling http method with another input value.

Comment: and what version are you using? or more precise what version of http-client you want to use?

Comment: It is doesn't matter. I want to know how to improve my example and I want to be sure I will not have problems with Observable. Do I have to use unsubscribe method there?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that at the moment I have no way to test this code, and therefore I doubt you can copy and paste this as-is and have it work.  Instead, my hope is this can give you an idea of another way to approach this problem.  Note that this uses the latest syntax for rxjs (6+) and requires the following imports:

`import { defer, throwError } from 'rxjs';`

and

`import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Here is the suggested code:

```
public callValue = 'first value';

public someMethod(): void {
    this.subscribedMethod = defer(() => {
        return this.someService.update(this.callValue).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err.status === 404) {
                    this.callValue = 'second value';
                }
                return throwError(err);
            }),
            retry(1)
        )
    })
        .subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                if (data) {
                    // do something
                }
            },
            (err: any) => {
                // if we reach here it is after failure of 2nd attempt
            });
}
```